# HTML/CSS Google fonts not loading

Tags: html, css, google-fonts

Here are 2 images of my HTML work and CSS as well. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but the google fonts will not load. I've tried using a different browser but that didn't help either. The browser that I've been mainly using is Google Chrome and I've also tried out Safari. I've also tried using different fonts but that hasn't made any difference either. I've added the code down below.

:[HTML Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLwUU.png)

:[CSS Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZWhf.png)

Html Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>Ray's site</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans|Montserrat|Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />

  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="topContainer">
          <img class="top-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
            <h1>I'm Ray.</h1>
            <p>a <span class="pro">pro</span>grammer.</p>
            <img class="bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
            <img  src="images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-img">
      </div>

      <div class="middleContainer">

      </div>

      <div class="bottomContainer">

      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body    {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', ;

}

h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-family: 'Sacramento', ;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', ;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', ;
}

.topContainer {
    background-color: #E4F9F5;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.middleContainer {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;


}

.bottomContainer {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;


}

.pro {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.top-cloud {
    position: absolute;
    right: 300px;
    top: 50px;

  }

.bottom-cloud {
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    bottom: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Please include code as text, not images, preferably as a [mcve] . Make it as easy as possible for us to help you by not having us have to retype your code.

Comment: You are missing the `<html>` opening tag in your index.html

Comment: Ah nice catch. I added it but still no fonts showing up.

Comment: How are you loading the web page? Have you tried adding the https:// in from of the font link?

Comment: I've done that and it didn't work either.

Comment: What does "will not load" mean? Do you know if it's the googleapis.com stylesheet that doesn't load, or if it's the actual font files that the stylesheet tries to load which don't load?  What is the error (if any) in the Network tab?

Answer (score 4):

Remove the trailing commas after your font names and it'll work (not sure why it doesn't work anyway, but I tried your code with and without the trailing commas and the latter works):

```
body    {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Merriweather Sans'; /* <- removed comma */

}

h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-family: 'Sacramento'; /* <- removed comma */
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat'; /* <- removed comma */
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat'; /* <- removed comma */
}
```

Btw, I went to Google Fonts and they're giving you that code (with the trailing comma), which is likely a bug on their end - normally what's after that comma in the code Google Fonts give you to paste is a fallback generic font (like "sans-serif" or whatever) - you should use one of those too.  But the code above will work for you.

Comment: Something so small was what was making my code not work. Thank  You!